# Android : Share intent is not working for video file path

Tags: java, android, video, android-intent, share-intent

I have a video file path and want to share the video on social media, but unable to share the video. I am trying following code in Android Studio 2.2, but it's not working.

Code snippet :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button shareBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);

    shareBtn .setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    File f = new File("/sdcard/VID_20161201123613.mp4");
                    Uri uriPath = Uri.parse(f.getPath());

                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");                  
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriPath);
                    shareIntent.setType("video/*");
                    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));

                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: U want to show list to share

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 5):

Try This :

```
public void shareVideo(final String title, String path) {

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[] { path },

            null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("video/*");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(
                            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(
                            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    shareIntent
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,
                            getString(R.string.str_share_this_video)));

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: It gives an error while sharing on WhatsApp - The file format is not supported and for Gmail - Can't attach empty file.

Comment: which type of video you want to share ?

Comment: http://www.androidcode.ninja/android-share-intent-example/     check this link thats exactly you want

Comment: Hey, thanks for share, It works for youtube, but not able to share on twitter. anythin else for twitter ?

Comment: suv what problem?

Comment: This code  is not working for sharing videos via intent so is there any update?

Comment: on which platform you want to share ?

Comment: android oreo(8.0), I have done the required changes for fetching the URI of the video file using FileProvider.

Comment: i mean where do you want to share the video like fb,twiter?

Comment: twitter, whatsapp, etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191578/discussion-between-suv-and-ravish-sharma).

Comment: any update or  this method won't work for whatsapp?

Comment: @RavishSharma video working fine, but Text is not showing

Answer (score 1):

use this code for pick an video from SD card then send email with video....

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("video/3gp");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Video");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://sdcard/dcim/Camera/filename.3gp"));
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enjoy the Video");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code to share video

```
fun shareVideo(filePath:String) {

    val videoFile = File(filePath)
    val videoURI = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(baseContext, baseContext.packageName, videoFile)
    else
        Uri.fromFile(videoFile)
    ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setStream(videoURI)
            .setType("video/mp4")
            .setChooserTitle("Share video...")
            .startChooser()



}
```